# Arranging 3 types of balls

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

Say we have $3n$ balls of 3 types:
1,...,n big balls
1,...,n medium sized balls
1,...,n small balls

I'd like to arrange them in triples so that every triple contains one of each type, but in each triple, the three balls mustn't have the same index. [Edit] The order of the triples is irrelevant [\Edit]. E.g. if we decide that the first coordinate is "big balls" and the last is "small ball" than the triple (i,i,i) is forbidden.

My approach is to use inclusion–exclusion principle. Let $p_i$ - Big ball number i is in the same triple with small ball number i and medium balls number i.

Then we get:

$w(p_i)=[(n-r)!]^2\leftarrow$arranging the rest of the balls in triples

$w(1)=n\cdot[(n-r)!]^2\leftarrow$by symmetry

$w(r)={n\choose r}\cdot[(n-r)!]^2\leftarrow$by symmetry

We find $E[0]$ which says that non of the $p_i$ happens:

$E[0]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^r\cdot w(r)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^r\cdot {n\choose r}\cdot[(n-r)!]^2$

Is this correct?

Comment: If only (i,i,i) is forbidden (for each "i" of course), then in my belief the total number of such arrangements should be (n!)^3 - n! (From total number of arranging those balla in triples such that in each triple u have 3x different size balls (n!*n!*n! ways), u remove those arrangements in which u have (i,i,i) type (n! ways).

Comment: @DominikKutek that only counts the number of arrangements such that there is at least one triple not of the form (i,i,i).  That is different than counting the number of arrangements such that no triple is of the form (i,i,i).

Comment: @DominikKutek First of all, the total number of arrangments can't be $(n!)^3$ since you count the same arrangments several times. The total number of arrangments should be in this case $(n!)^2$ because for each "small ball" we choose the medium ball (that's $n!$) and later we choose the big ball ($n!$). Secondly, I don't get the calculation of the forbidden ways... I'd be happy if you can explain it more deeply. If I wasn't clear, the triples don't have identifiers.

Comment: @E_K from that, do I understand correctly that the order in which the triples occur is irrelevant?

Comment: Yes, it's irrelevant

Comment: Okay, so my apologize, I was pretty sure, the triples really do have identifiers.

Comment: It sounds to me like inclusion-exclusion is the way to go, going through a similar approach as to deriving the formula for the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) using inclusion-exclusion.  As for @E_K's current attempt in the post, I do not understand the notation you are using with $w$.

Comment: @JMoravitz $w(p_i)$ (as I know it) means - numbers of elements that maintain the feature $p_i$. For $0\leq i\leq n:$ $w(r)$ means the number of elements that maintain r features (at least)

Comment: In that case, yes, it sounds correct.